# How to make player stop infinite jump in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

So I'm new to unity only 2 days, and I'm having this problem of my player jumping in air. I can keep clicking the spacebar key and my player will keep jumping and not stop, I'm trying make it so the player can only jump while on the ground not the air. I been trying a lot of tutorials  and most of them just made my game freeze up and not work anymore. I also been trying to find out how to use ground check but I'm still not sure on how to do that.

This is my code that I have right know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PM : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    Rigidbody2D rb;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update() {
    float moveDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir, rb.velocity.y);

    // Your jump code:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need some sort of ground check. There are a lot of good tutorials online, for example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3iEl5AwUF8&t=17s ("3 ways to do a Ground Check in Unity").

To implement the simple "raycast down check", you need to assign the ground/platforms a layermask that is not the same as the player's layer. In this example, I have added a new layer named "Ground".

[image]

You can then use this simple code to do the test.

```
BoxCollider2D boxColliderPlayer;
int layerMaskGround;
float heightTestPlayer;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    // Get the player's collider so we can calculate the height of the character.
    boxColliderPlayer = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    // We do the height test from the center of the player, so we should only check
    // halft the height of the player + some extra to ignore rounding off errors.
    heightTestPlayer = boxColliderPlayer.bounds.extents.y + 0.05f;
    // We are only interested to get colliders on the ground layer. If we would
    // like to jump ontop of enemies we should add their layer too (which then of
    // course can't be on the same layer as the player).
    layerMaskGround = LayerMask.GetMask("Ground");
}

void Update()
{
    float moveDir = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveDir, rb.velocity.y);

    // Your jump code:
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded() )
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpHeight);
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Simple check to see if our character is no the ground. 
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if the character is grounded.</returns>
private bool IsGrounded()
{
    // Note that we only check for colliders on the Ground layer (we don't want to hit ourself). 
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down, heightTestPlayer, layerMaskGround);
    bool isGrounded = hit.collider != null;
    // It is soo easy to make misstakes so do a lot of Debug.DrawRay calls when working with colliders...
    Debug.DrawRay(boxColliderPlayer.bounds.center, Vector2.down * heightTestPlayer, isGrounded ? Color.green : Color.red, 0.5f);
    return isGrounded;
}
```

As you can see I expect the player character to have a BoxCollider2D - I guess you already have that since the character would otherwise fall through the ground). Be careful so you do not mix normal 3D colliders when you are doing 2D stuff.