# hello, i was recently working on my new game, and im getting a problem with *Infinite jumping*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

so basically when I press jump/spacebar I jump but if I press spacebar continuously it
just jumps and jumps and jumps and so on..., which I don't want I just want it to jump once.

code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && !isGrounded) 
    {
      velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
      isGrounded = true;
    }
```

let me know if you want to see all of the code, Thanks!.

Comment: Have a look at : [How to make player stop infinite jump in unity 2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66938446/how-to-make-player-stop-infinite-jump-in-unity-2d)

Comment: That code is saying to jump only if the character is not grounded and then to mark the player as grounded. Seems backwards — presumably you’d want it to jump only if the player is grounded (assuming that means on the ground) and then you’d want to mark the player as no longer on the ground (grounded=false)?

Comment: that's the problem, if i do the code backwards, and play in unity it wont jump when i press space which gave me a headache but when i made it so that you only jump when your not grounded and mark it as grounded after i was able to jump but i would jump infinitely, i can give you my whole code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have a problem somewhere else in your code where `isGrounded` is being set to `false` when you don't want it to be. Have you tried doing a Raycast down from the bottom of the player, then setting `isGrounded` to `true` if that raycast is shorter than a certain length?