# im getting a problem with infinite jumps into the air

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im acttualy losing my mind at this point, been having this issue for the past 3 days, cant figure out any solutions, this might sound lazy and all but if you can troubleshoot my code
that'd great because i dont wanna lose more sanity, Thanks in Advance

code:

public class playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public CharacterController controller;

public float speed = 12f;

Vector3 velocity;

public float gravity = -9.81f;

public Transform groundCheck;

public float groundDistance = 0.4f;

public LayerMask groundMask;

bool isGrounded;

public float jumpHeight = 3f;

void Start() 
{ 
 isGrounded = true;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
     isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

     if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
     {
         velocity.y = -2f;
     }
     
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
      velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    
    }
       
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }

    if ()
    {
        
    }


    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);


}
```

}

Comment: didn't you [ask this yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71988221/hello-i-was-recently-working-on-my-new-game-and-im-getting-a-problem-with-inf)?

Comment: i did, and i tried the answers but they arnt working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forcing isGrounded to false when you push space, try removing that, and you aren't actually checking isGrounded to perform the jump. Here's a bandaid

```html
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
      if (isGrounded){
      velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
      } else return;
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i tried to do it but it isn't working, i removed the

Comment: Can you not jump now? Then your problem is with the isGrounded bool. Perhaps your physics.checksphere isnt big enough, is too small, or is incorrectly positioned. Checking ground this way doesn't work very well for character controllers, which you seem to be using. Why not use CharacterController.IsGrounded() ?

Comment: sorry for cutting the sentence i had a black out, anyways, i tried your code and removed the old one but it gives me like 5-3 console errors, the reason i dont use CharacterController.IsGrounded() is because, tobe honest i littrely joined coding 5 dyas ago, so i dont know what to do i just followed brackeys fps movement video, it all went alright untill i wanted to prevent the infinite jumping, however i will try to do what you just said, Thanks!

Comment: alright, i tried messing with the physics.checksphere but it doesnt seem to work?, can  you tell me where i can use the CharacterController.isGrounded(), Thanks

Comment: The code I gave definitely shouldn't throw console errors... Either way, to inject CharacterController.isGrounded(), all you need to do is replace your physics.checksphere.

    `isGrounded = controller.isGrounded;`

Comment: hello, so i tried this statement:            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && controller.isGrounded)
        {
                    
         velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
          
        }, it works now i cant jump infinitely, but it is a bit laggy tho, i wont jump if im not moving for example, i cna only jump when im walking in a direction

Comment: and sometimes it doesnt jump even tho im moving, but i will just get over it i dont even care at this point, THANKS ALOT FRIEND! 